# Cannot add contributors on a LUIS app using Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-language-understanding

Recently, we started using Microsoft LUIS from a Azure Account, with the desire to give access to some LUIS Apps (created by a Azure Admin Account), trying to assign these permissions to users (inside the corporation) for the contribution.

We tried to add the Contributor Role for the Azure authoring resource, but without results. After giving this access, our users reported that the LUIS platform is displaying a popup, with recommendations to switching the Azure directory. What happens is that the LUIS platform freezes, and no options are displayed to continue the process, without any Directory to go ahead.

Does anyone can recommend any other action, or even a role that we need to add for a LUIS APP Contributor?

Tried to follow these steps below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-collaborate

[image]

Comment: This behavior seems inconsistent, please use the following link to open an MS suport ticket.
https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/newsupportrequest

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not reproducible. For intermittent issues please contact Microsoft Support.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a investigation done by the Microsoft team, they have discovered a very specific case when Azure admins have enabled conditional access policy requiring MFA. This was causing some breaks on LUIS portal.

The fix was successfully applied, and the Portal is working properly.

I Would like to thank all of you for the taskforce to fix the portal.

**Detailed thread**:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/240393/cannot-add-contributors-on-a-luis-app-using-azure.html